# Installed imagick on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: php, imagemagick, windows-server-2008-r2, imagick

So, I've been at it all day and about to give up, but thought posting my question would be a good last chance.  I know this is difficult, but not impossible, since I've read the stories from many on the same topic and they all seem to get there eventually.

I'm trying to install Imagick (the PHP DLL for Imagemagick) on Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit.  I am using the thread-safe version of PHP and had the server running perfectly fine before trying the install.  Here are the steps I've already taken:

1. I installed the **GPL GhostsScript** package (gs905w64.exe) since ImageMagick asked for it to be installed prior to ImageMagick itself.  Ok, next...
2. Downloaded **"ImageMagick-6.6.2-10-Q16-windows-x64-dll.exe"** and installed it to path  C:\imagemagick.  According to the internets, this seems to be the version of choice for this server/DLL mix.  I tried 4 other installs, including the latest version, and this so far seemed the best fit.  After install, the command line steps it says to take with "logo.miff" worked fine. After the install and test, I confirmed that the installation path showed up in my Environment Variables correctly. Great... next.
3. Downloaded **"php_imagick_ts.dll"** from [here](http://valokuva.org/builds/), saved it to my extensions folder (yes, the correct one) and added it to my php.ini file (also the correct one).  Since that didn't work, I tried all 3 versions of the thread-safe DLLs on that same download page.  None of those worked either, so I tried the non-thread-safe versions as well with no luck.  I also tried the **php_imagick_dyn-Q16.dll** available from [here](http://valokuva.org/outside-blog-content/imagick-windows-builds/080709/), as well as the static version too.  The static version finally worked after everything.
4. I installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributals (both the main and SP1 versions).  This seemed to have no effect on anything.

Final result after all of this: "imagick" shows up in my phpinfo(), but doesn't work and extension_loaded('magickwand') returns false.  I'm assuming my installation failed here.  Can you let me know what I'm doing wrong?